# SPARQL query to get all the "leaf" classes / lowest level classes

Tags: sparql, owl, protege, rdfs, linked-data

I feel like I'm missing something rather obvious. I would like to query my graph so that I get all the "leafs", so **any class that does not have a subclass**. Basically, I need the inverse of rdfs:hasSubClass (I tried rdfs:superClassOf but it doesn't not exist ahaha).

For example, when I query for the lowest level of the classes by using
WHERE
{?level1 subClassOf ?level2
?level2 subClassOf ?level3
?level3 subClassOf ?level4
etc.}

I eventually end up with kind of what I want: some of the leafs. But if I then join this result to the leafs of one level higher, I also receive the parent classes of the leafs of the query above, which I do not want. I only want children classes, no parents, if that makes sense.

The goal is to be able to output a list of classes that can be instantiated.

Looking for any tips in the right direction! Thank you!

Comment: why would you need the "inverse" of `rdfs:subClassOf`? An RDF triple looks like `<A> rdfs:subClassOf `<B> .` - so in your SPARQL query you would use a triple pattern `?sub rdfs:subClassOf ?sup .` and either select `?sub` or `?sup`

Comment: to get all leaf nodes just get all classes that do not have a subclass. Absence of something is done via `FILTER NOT EXISTS` clause. Like `select distinct ?cls {?cls rdfs:subClassOf ?sup . FILTER NOT EXISTS{?sub rdfs:subClassOf ?cls FILTER(?sub != ?cls && ?sub != owl:Nothing ) }}`

Comment: Thank you! I think I confused myself a bit with the subclassof command. You helped me see the light even though it looks obvious now! As for your second comment, this works as far as I can tell comparing it to my test set, so I will build upon this. Thank you! Not sure how to mark a thread as solved, but consider it solved :)

Comment: you can mark it as "solved" if you provide the final solution as an answer and also accept it. And yes, you can add an accepted answer for your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An RDF triple looks like  rdfs:subClassOf  .` - so in your SPARQL query you would use a triple pattern ?sub rdfs:subClassOf ?sup . and either select ?sub or ?sup

to get all leaf nodes just get all classes that do not have a subclass. Absence of something is done via FILTER NOT EXISTS clause. Like select distinct ?cls {?cls rdfs:subClassOf ?sup . FILTER NOT EXISTS{?sub rdfs:subClassOf ?cls FILTER(?sub != ?cls && ?sub != owl:Nothing ) }}

Credits to UninformedUser for this solution!